# Unable To Load Images using AsyncTask

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I have a scenario where I need to retrieve the images from URL upon loading my home page. The home page consists of 30 images out of which only 10 gets loaded initially. And further upon scrolling,other images are retrieved.(I dont mean PullToRefresh functionality). I am setting the images in a StaggeredGridView(a library from Github). I am able to **load all the images from WebService call** and able to print its name in the logcat but **not able to set all the images except the first one**. And upon scrolling which calls the 2nd asyn task which loads the next 10 images images, also sets only image from the 2nd async task which is also the first image.(Referring the 11th image here). I have called notifyDataSetChanged to the adapter but it throws a NullPointerException.

**CODE :**

**WebServicesClass :**

The contents of doInBackGround() are as follows :

```
               String image_url = "http://demo.bsetec.com/fancyclone/uploads/approved_items/"
                                        + first_image;
                                // System.out.println("The image url is " +
                                // image_url);
                                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                                    throw new IOException(
                                            "Not an HTTP connection");

                                try {

                                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                    httpConn.connect();

                                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                                        compressed_image = image;

                                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                        options.inPurgeable = true;
                                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                                        options.inSampleSize = 1;
                                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,
                                                null, options);

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                                }


                                item = new RowItem(image, product_name, cost,
                                        product_id, dream_status,username);
                                rowItems.add(item);
```

where item is the object of holder class which has get,set methods and rowItems is the object of a List whose type is holder class.

**MainActivty.java :**

```
 mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        new WebServicesClass();



        mGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);

        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList(SAVED_DATA_KEY, mData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged:" + scrollState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onScroll firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem +
                            " visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount +
                            " totalItemCount:" + totalItemCount);
        // our handling
        if (!mHasRequestedMore) {

            System.out.println("Inside the requested more");
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
          //  if (lastInScreen >= totalItemCount) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onScroll lastInScreen - so load more");
                mHasRequestedMore = true;
                new WebServicesClass().onLoadMoreItems();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mHasRequestedMore = false;
            //}
        }
    }
```

I'll be happy to help with any clarifications. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can us eimageloader..:)

Comment: I don't have any problems with loading images, I am just missing something that restricts me from displaying all the images.

Comment: ok..,i find another way for your answer....:)